# Does the mySql WEEK() function work for columns with type DATE?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Does the WEEK() function work for columns with type DATE or does it require a column to have type DATETIME?

Various SO searches suggest this should work, but this statement provides an empty result:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_benutzer WHERE WEEK(dob,1) = WEEK(CURDATE(),1) ORDER BY id DESC
```

For example, a recordset where dob is 1972-07-09 is not recognised when today's date is 2014-07-07.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: What you want? Have you got any error?

Comment: That should work just fine with `DATE`.

Comment: I'm getting an empty result with this SQL statement. For example a record with 1972-07-09 is not recognised when today's date is 2014-07-07

Comment: The result of `SELECT WEEK('1972-07-09', 1) as week_dob, WEEK('2014-07-07', 1) as week_today;` is `27 | 28`, see this [fiddle] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f05b/1). Those values are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date), it extract only the date part from a date/datetime value.

Your query will be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_benutzer WHERE WEEK(DATE(dob),1) = WEEK(CURDATE(),1) ORDER BY id DESC
```